# ASP.Net MVC Getting HTTP 400 with ajax post request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to post some simple data with ajax from my view to controller. When I switch it to HttpGet it works fine, but when trying httppost I always get error 400.
Here is my view code:

```
@Html.Hidden("postSettings", Url.Action("MethodName", "MyController"))
$.ajax({
     url: $("#postSettings").val(),
     type: "POST",
     data: JSON.stringify(11),
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json",
     success: function (_result) {
         console.log("success")
     },
     error: function (e) {
         console.log(e);
         }
});
```

And code in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult MethodName(object value)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not noticed that I have global filter applied

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
        });
```

,adding the CSRF token fixed the problem.
I just added this code to my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gettoken() {
        var token = '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()';
        token = $(token).val();
        return token;
    }
</script>
```

And to the ajax request:

```
headers: {
    RequestVerificationToken: gettoken()
},
```